# I want to use Shared Preferences on TextView if text is get from another Activity and OnBackpressed function

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to store text which I have get from Another Intent, I have already tried to used `SharedPreferences` but not successfully stored.

And Another issue is when I pressed backbutton mainactivity show dialogue but not closed application. It is going on another activity from where I am getting data and when I used this line onbackedpressed  `Catering.this.finish();` MainActivity open again onbackpressed but not close application.
I cannot use nohistory because I am moving data between activities.....

> here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
TextView total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    total.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));

    CurvedBottomNavigationView mView = findViewById(R.id.customBottomBar);
        mView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);
        mView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.budget);
        mView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.budget:
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Catering.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.food:
            break;
        case R.id.EEC:
            break;
        case R.id.Venue:
            break;


    }
    return true;
}

  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();

    }

}
```

> Another Activity from where I am fetching data on MainActivity creates backpressed issue...

```
public class Catering extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
EditText edt1, edt2,edt3,edt4,edt5,edt6;
TextView tv;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private Object TextWatcher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catering);

    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.starters);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.breakfast);
    edt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lunch);
    edt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dinner);
    edt5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.drinks);
    edt6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.deserts);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    edt1.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    edt2.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    edt3.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    edt4.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    edt5.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    edt6.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Expences", MODE_PRIVATE);

    tv.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("exp","hello"));

    edt1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt1",addNumbers()));
    edt2.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt2",addNumbers()));
    edt3.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt3",addNumbers()));
    edt4.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt4",addNumbers()));
    edt5.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt5",addNumbers()));
    edt6.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("edt6",addNumbers()));
}

public TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        tv.setText(addNumbers());

        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("exp", addNumbers());
        edit.apply();
        tv.setText( addNumbers());
    }

    @Override

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};


private String addNumbers() {
    long number1;
    long number2;
    long number3;
    long number4;
    long number5;
    long number6;
    if (edt1.getText().toString() != "" && edt1.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Long.parseLong(edt1.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt1", String.valueOf(number1));
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if (edt2.getText().toString() != "" && edt2.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Long.parseLong(edt2.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt2", String.valueOf(number2));
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }

    if (edt3.getText().toString() != "" && edt3.getText().length() > 0) {
        number3 = Long.parseLong(edt3.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt3", String.valueOf(number3));
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number3 = 0;
    }
    if (edt4.getText().toString() != "" && edt4.getText().length() > 0) {
        number4 = Long.parseLong(edt4.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt4", String.valueOf(number4));
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number4 = 0;
    }
    if (edt5.getText().toString() != "" && edt5.getText().length() > 0) {
        number5 = Long.parseLong(edt5.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt5", String.valueOf(number5));
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number5 = 0;
    }
    if (edt6.getText().toString() != "" && edt6.getText().length() > 0) {
        number6 = Long.parseLong(edt6.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putString("edt6", String.valueOf(number6));
        edit.commit();
    } else {
        number6 = 0;
    }
    return Long.toString(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5 + number6);
}

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Catering.this,MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("mytext",addNumbers());
        Catering.this.finish();
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `startActivityForResult`

```
case R.id.budget:
    Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Catering.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    break;
```

in `Catering.class`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    myIntent.putExtra("mytext",addNumbers());
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,myIntent);
    finish();
}
```

get the result in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String mytext=data.getStringExtra("mytext");
            total.setText(mytext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working.. first comment code is starting mainactivity again. Where should I place this code?

Comment: Not working in my case, I am using catering activity( edittexts with add function and answer in textview with textwatcher ) and then pass data from catering to mainactivity where i pass textview intent and again show on textview. a/c to ur code activity change and ans show on mainactivity only...

Comment: I also want to store MainActivity data on sharedpreferences